# Weird behavior of spread operator in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx, spread

**Spread Operator in JS environment**

```
let obj1 = {a:1,b:2}
let obj2 = {...obj1}
console.log(obj2)
```

`Above code outputs {a:1,b:2} Which is a copy of obj1`

**Spread Operator in JSX**
let us assume this.props = {lib:'react',lang:'js'}

`<App {...this.props}/>`
would be same as
`<App lib={this.props.lib} lang={this.props.lang}>` 
As we know this.props is also an object just like obj1 why does JSX spreads like lib='react,lang='js' instead of lib:'react',lang:'js'?
Is there a difference between JSX Spread Operator and Javascript Spread Operator?
I'm really Confused

Answer (score 1):

> As we know this.props is also an object just like obj1 why does JSX
> spreads differently?

The `{}` syntax in JSX is used for JavaScript expressions, so when we use `{}` it isn't considered as an object literal.

That's the reason we use something like `someProp={{bla: 'foo'}}` when we want to pass an object because the outer pair is to tell that we will have an expression inside it.

In short, using `{}` in JSX doesn't create an object.

You can read more about [spread attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes).

Comment: _But we cannot send props to a Component like below right?_                                  `<App {lib:'react',lang:'js'} />` **Because inside { } in JSX can be seen as Javascript which is not meaningful in the above Code snippet**

Comment: @Santhosh: Right we cannot send props to be a Component like you have shown, That's why we spread them and they are added as values to props object, Then we need to de-Structure those or extract from props object. I think you yourself answered half your question now. I have updated my answer. Have a look. I believe you will get to know the stuff

Answer (score 0):

In both cases it is a spread operator only and Javascript spread operator only. There is no such thing as JSX spread operator.

When we do `<App {...this.props}/>`, it is same as `<App a="1" b="2"/>` in React.
And in React these are added to the prop object of App class. From that prop object, we get access to the values `a` and `b` respectively.

```
const App = (props)=>{
   const {a,b} = props; // Object De-structuring
}
```

We are basically spreading the props which means passing these values as Props to the App component, . This is same as passing values to function using spread operator.

Think of it this way: Think of `App Component` as a function, which is taking spreaded object as arguments.

```
const App= ({a,b})=>{ // Here we are De-Structuring from our props object
   console.log(a);
   console.log(b);
}

App({...obj1}); // This is same as App(a,b)
```

Codepen code : https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/poEREEx?editors=1111

Try above code in Javascript file

Spread `...` operator can also be used to make a clone of the object when we do

```
let obj1 = {a:1,b:2}

let obj2 = {...obj1}
```

`obj2` is clone of obj1. A complete new object. obj1 and obj2 are now two different objects in memory not just the references.

Comment: Just a thought came to my mind .I think I can make you understand this way. So basically we spread our values and they are passed as props individually to props object. And from that props object we get our values. Hope you get it now. If not I will explain again :) I now realize that your question is spot on. Nice Question bro. Let me update the answer if I need to. I will first cross check

Comment: Dear @Imran Could u please look at the comments in this                                                  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018148/spread-syntax-this-props-in-reactjs-feels-odd) which describes my whole point

Comment: Will hopefully check it tomorrow mate... It's getting too late now..